# Remove two substrings from a string

Tags: string, bash

I have a list of files like this:

```
wgEncodeCaltechRnaSeqGm12878R1x75dFastqRep1.fastq.trim.tags.sam
wgEncodeCaltechRnaSeqGm12878R1x75dFastqRep2.fastq.trim.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd1Rep1.fastq.trim00.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd1Rep1.fastq.trim01.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd1Rep1.fastq.trim02.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd1Rep2.fastq.trim00.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd1Rep2.fastq.trim01.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd1Rep2.fastq.trim02.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd2Rep1.fastq.trim00.tags.sam
wgEncodeCshlLongRnaSeqGm12878CellPapFastqRd2Rep1.fastq.trim01.tags.sam
```

I want to remove the Rd1, Rd2 and .sam stings from their file names. With the following bash script, I can remove the Rd1, Rd2 and .sam strings using two commands....

```
for i in $(ls)

do

echo "${i/Rd?/}"
echo "${i/.sam/}"

done
```

But I want to know how to do the two substitutions in one step
Do you know how to do it?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: use `for i in *` not `for i in $(ls)` -- the first form will work properly for files with spaces in the name, the second will split those names.

Comment: I didn't knew it, but I don't have files with spaces..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use extended patterns to do it all in `bash`.

```
shopt -s extglob
echo ${i//@(Rd?|.sam)}
```

Here's the breakdown:

1. Use `//` to replace all occurrences of the pattern, not just the first.
2. `@(Rd?|.sam)` is an extended pattern, which matches *either* `Rd?` or `.sam`. The
    pipe separates the two sub-patterns.

Technically, you'd like to be able to avoid removing ".sam" from the middle of the word,
but it looks like this is safe for your use case.

Comment: `shopt` is the general bash command for manipulating shell options. The `-s` flag indicates that the named option that follows is to be set. You can turn off extended pattern matching by issuing `shopt -u extglob` after you are done using them.

Comment: I haven't found a way. According to the bash man page, `${i/%.sam}` would work, but that can't be combined with the extended patterns. `${i//@(Rd?|%.sam)}` didn't work for me.

Answer (score 4):

Of course we know!

```
for i in *
do
   echo $i | sed 's/Rd.//;s/\.sam$//'
done
```

And when you want rename these files:

```
for i in *
do
   mv "$i" "$(echo $i | sed 's/Rd.//;s/\.sam$//')"
done
```

Comment: I don't want to rename the files, but with "$(echo $i | sed 's/Rd.//;s/\.sam$//')" I can do what I want!
Thanks!!

Comment: @IgorChubin  Green... my preecious!!

Comment: with bash, you can use a here-string instead of `echo $i`: `$(sed '...' <<< "$i")`